# Trying to check whole numbers in php

Tags: php

The function below is trying to find whole numbers.
But somehow I'm not doing this right as it shows every number to be whole (no digits after .)

`$max_value % 1` should only return true is there is no rest value??

Can anyone help me, now every check gives 0 as result.

Hope I explain well what I mean

solution(30);

```
function solution($a){

 $sides_short = array();
 $sides_long  = array();
 $max_number  = $a/2;
 $total = $a;

 for($i=1;$i<=$max_number;$i++){
    $min_value = $i;
    $max_value = $a / $min_value;
    echo "loop values: ".$min_value." x ".$max_value."<br>";

    if($max_value % 1 == 0) {
        echo ($max_value % 1) ."<br>";
        echo "Aproved: (".$min_value." x ".$max_value.") $max_value % 1 = ".($max_value % 1)."<br><br>";
        $sides_short[] = $min_value; 
        $sides_long[] = $max_value;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: Modulo (`%`) is not defined for floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The modulo operator `%` is not defined for floating point numbers, so you can not use modulo here. You can cast the `float` to an `int` and check, if both, the `float` and the `int` are equal. They can only be equal if the `float` was a number without any decimal places, as the cast to `int` would strip any decimal places and therefore make them unequal if there were any in the float.

```
$float = 1.5;
var_dump($float == intval($float));
$float = 1.0;
var_dump($float == intval($float));
```

Produces the output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Actually, you can do it with floats too, just have to use [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) (had someone mention that). Added an example to my answer but thought you might like to know

Answer (score 2):

You're using a modulo. That divides by that number and returns the remainder.

```
$x = 3 % 2; // $x = 1
```

3 goes into 2 once, and leaves a remainder of 1

Anything divided by 1 is that number, with a remainder of 0. Therefore, this statement is always true.

```
if($max_value % 1 == 0)
```

Also, if you modulus a floating number, it will also be 0

```
var_dump(8 % 1.5); // int(0)
```

If you really need to modulus a float, use [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

```
var_dump(fmod(8, 1.5)); // float(0.5)
```